# Ajax Chrome wont evaluate script immediately in success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have this source:

```
$("#allDataForm").submit( function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var formData = $("#allDataForm").serialize();
    var count = formData.substring(formData.indexOf('&count=')+7,formData.indexOf('&x='));
    var x = parseInt(formData.substring(formData.indexOf('&x=')+3, formData.length));
    if (formData.indexOf('=description&') > 0 && 
        formData.indexOf('=name&') > 0 && 
        formData.indexOf('=identifier&') > 0) {
        
        var head = 0;
        if (formData.indexOf('firstashead=on') > 0) {
            head=1;
        }
        head = parseInt(head);
        var imported = 0;
        var updated = 0;
        $("#assignTable").hide();
        $("#send").hide();
        $("#status").show();
        var totalTime = 0;
        if (count > 0) {
            for (s=x; s<=count; s++) {
                var startms = new Date().getTime();
                $.ajax({   
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "html",  
                    url: "/import/universalimport/",  
                    async: false, 
                    success: function(msg, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        console.log($.makeArray(arguments), 'success');
                        console.log(textStatus, 'success1');
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest, 'success2');
                        if (msg == 'imported') {
                            imported = parseInt(imported)+1;
                        } else if (msg == 'updated') {
                            updated = parseInt(updated)+1;
                        }
                        var endms = new Date().getTime();
                        totalTime = totalTime + (endms-startms);
                        x = totalTime / 1000;
                        tSeconds = Math.abs((x % 60).toFixed(0));
                        if (tSeconds < 10) {
                            tSeconds = 0+String(tSeconds);
                        }
                        x /= 60;
                        tMinutes = Math.abs((x % 60).toFixed(0));
                        if (tMinutes < 10) {
                            tMinutes = 0+String(tMinutes);
                        }
                        x /= 60;
                        tHours = Math.abs((x % 24).toFixed(0));
                        if (tHours < 10) {
                            tHours = 0+String(tHours);
                        }
                        x = (totalTime*(count-s-head)/s) / 1000;
                        aSeconds = Math.abs((x % 60).toFixed(0));
                        if (aSeconds < 10) {
                            aSeconds = 0+String(aSeconds);
                        }
                        x /= 60;
                        aMinutes = Math.abs((x % 60).toFixed(0));
                        if (aMinutes < 10) {
                            aMinutes = 0+String(aMinutes);
                        }
                        x /= 60;
                        aHours = Math.abs((x % 24).toFixed(0));
                        if (aHours < 10) {
                            aHours = 0+String(aHours);
                        }
                        eval($("#bar").css('width', (parseInt(s)/parseInt(count)*100).toFixed(2) + '%'));
                        $("#bar").html((parseInt(s)/parseInt(count)*100).toFixed(2) + '%');
                        $("#imported").html(imported);
                        $("#updated").html(updated);
                        $("#summary").html(imported+updated);
                        $("#count").html(count-head);
                        $("#elapsed").html(tHours + ':' + tMinutes + ':' + tSeconds);
                        $("#remaining").html(aHours + ':' + aMinutes + ':' + aSeconds);
                        formData = formData.substring(0, formData.indexOf('&x=')+3) + parseInt(s);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert('Pro provedení importu je nutno napárovat minimálně Název, Popis a Identifikátor!');
    }
    return false;
});
```

In Google Chrome it wont evaluate script inside success immediately but after all ajax calls it execute the last one. When I add `alert()` inside success it works fine and in Firefox it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by recursive calling asynchronous ajax. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Async is a depreciated feature.  Success is also on its way out.  You should be using

```
$.ajax({   
     type: "POST",
     data: formData,
     dataType: "html",  
     url: "/import/universalimport/"
     }).done(msg, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
       ... rest of code when done here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3wkx/4/) showing a set of $.ajax() POSTs being sent all at once and coming back at different intervals:

```
<ul id='log'></ul>
<script>
var call,
    log = $('#log');
for (call = 0; call < 10; call++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
            html: "ajax response #" + call,
            delay: 3
        },
        success: function(data) {
            log.append('<li>'+data+'</li>')
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
    log.append('<li>'+('ajax request #' + call)+'</li>')
    console.log('ajax request #' + call);
}
</script>
```

I've run this in Chrome and Firefox and the behavior appears to be the same (the ajax responses return out of order as though they had been submitted at different intervals).  Does this model the problem you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks it may work but i can't waste time. This ajax must import 10000 products and if i could call it every 3 seconds it takes a lot of time. When i import images it takes more time and this functionality stop working. Any other ideas?